# Remote lookup between JBoss EAP 7.1 with ActiveMQ Artemis embedded fail

Tags: jms, jndi, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

I encounter some problems using remote JMS communication between 2 JBoss EAP 7.1 servers (with ActiveMQ Artemis embedded).
An EJB MDB, deployed on a second server, try to access Artemis queues deployed on a first server (same machine but different port).
The MDB client (XA use case) :
1)   consumes message from a request queue exported by the first server
2)  processes message content, including database updates
3)  sends a response to a reply queue exposrted by same remote server

So, first server exports 3 (Artemis) queues :
-   TestQueueReq, for requests consumed by 2nd app server 
-   TestQueueRep, for replies sent by 2nd app server 
-   DLQTestQueue, for dead letter queue

Extract from first server configuration:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
            <server name="default">
              <security enabled="false"/>
                <address-setting name="jms.queue.TestQueue#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQTestQueue" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" redelivery-delay="500" redelivery-multiplier="2.0" max-delivery-attempts="3" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
( …/…)
                <jms-queue name="DLQTestQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQTestQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="TestQueueReq" entries="java:/jms/queue/TestQueueReq java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQueueReq" durable="true"/>
                <jms-queue name="TestQueueRep" entries="java:/jms/queue/TestQueueRep java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQueueRep" durable="true"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

Second server is configured as documented in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/resource_adapters#use_provided_amq_adapter

```
      <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security enabled="false"/>
:…/…)
                <http-connector name="remote-http-connector" socket-binding="remote-server" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-http-connector"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

External context binding is also configured on the second server according to this official doc : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_naming_subsystem

Message sent to TestQueueReq is correctly consumed by MDB.

```
@ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "TestQueueReq")
    }, messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleSFBean implements ExampleSF, MessageListener {
@Override

  public void onMessage(final Message message) {
      …
```

The problem happens when we try, within the MDB, to send a message to the reply queue.
I have tried many different strategies for resource injection in the MDB :

```
  @Inject
  @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF")
  private JMSContext jmsContext;

  @Resource (lookup = "java:global/remoteContext")
  private Context remoteContext;

  @Resource (lookup="java:global/TestQueueRep")
  private Queue queueRep;
```

But we keep on getting exceptions when trying to send response, due to injection/lookup problems.

- jmsContext is null, except when MDB is @ApplicationContext annotated.
- queueRep injection does not work since the lookup fail (with : Invalid URL scheme name "null")
- Manual lookup using remoteContext fails with the, same as previous, following exception:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: WFNAM00007: Invalid URL scheme name
> ```
>
> "null"
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.subsystem.NamingBindingAdd$LookupManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(NamingBindingAdd.java:451)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.subsystem.NamingBindingAdd$MutableManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(NamingBindingAdd.java:354)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:143)
>       ... 99 more
>       Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: WFNAM00007: Invalid URL scheme name "null"
>       at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.getProviderContext(WildFlyRootContext.java:808)
>       at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:155)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)

- Question 1 : can someone tell me what is wrong with my code/configuration and why automatic injection of remote reply queue does not work ? Or, at least, why manual lookup from the remote context is not working? And what this scheme error means…
- Question 2 : if MDB is not @ApplicationScoped annotated, JMSContext is not injected (null). Is it normal ? If yes, is there any drawback annotating the MDB that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you create a application user on the message server with a role of guest if  not please see  this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef0HFbyaHFs
   In my case I had created user as MSGTEST with password "Welcome1!"  so your entry on other server should look like this.
2. Once you create that user you need add that you pooled connection factory 
   something like this with properties  **user="MSGTEST" password="Welcome1!"**

`<pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-http-connector"  transaction="xa" user="MSGTEST" password="Welcome1!" />`

3.Make sure @ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis") in your MDB  is from correct package **import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;**

As this did not WORK==> import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.ResourceAdapter;

Hope this helps. I create message server on machine1 and deployed MDB on Machine2. It worked.

Forgot to mention  in both cases I used standalone-full.xml as that has all subsystems for active MQ messageing. Only using standalone.xml will not work. BEWARE!